# what is the matter about the animator and Theme.AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-studio, objectanimator

when i create rotation.xml in the res/animator folder, the android studio always throw error:

```
Process: com.kycq.demo, PID: 23236
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kycq.demo/com.kycq.demo.LoadingActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:331)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
      at com.kycq.demo.LoadingActivity.onCreate(LoadingActivity.java:11)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoadingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

LoadingActivity.java:

```
public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kycq.demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

i don't know how to solve the problem, it made me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying providing the theme to activity also:

```
<activity
   android:name=".LoadingActivity"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: ok,it work.but must set the theme to every Activity?why set AppTheme can't work every Activity?

Comment: Anyway, it should have worked by adding theme attribute to `application`. But somehow, activity was unable to inherit it from application. BTW, adding theme attribute to each activity is not a bad idea.